# Is it possible to Odoo to install a module with a compiled python file?

Tags: python, installation, odoo, odoo-8, python-packaging

I am trying to install a module with a compiled python files(.pyc) to Odoo.

compiled meaning all my .py files are converted to .pyc

my goal here is to not show my code just for security purposes.

So i tried remove all the .py files and retain all the .pyc and tried to install it in odoo. unfortunately my module is not displaying on the module list.

If this is possible please give me a hint. or suggest me any solution and/or workaround.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Even if it works....hope you know your code can still be dis-assembled back to the original source code in less than a minute with https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2 making your whole effort to "hide" the code pointless

Comment: Relying on the compiled bytecode to obfuscate your code is pretty much a waste of time. If you *really* need to you can use a compiled language like C and distribute an .so or .dll and use python bindings to call the code you're trying to obfuscate. Either way, its probably not worth it unless it's a business requirement that justifies the effort.

Comment: Well guys I tried to revert back the __openerp__.py and the other files remain .pyc and yes it works. I installed the module.

Comment: Please Write a tut about it @Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Simply try creating a blank file named 'modulename.py' in the /models folder to test your configuration. After updating the apps list in developer mode, you should be able to find the module in the app store.